# Create new index using pandas by appending a comma

Tags: pandas

Currently the index in my data frame has the default values of 0,1,2 .. n-1 where n is the number of rows in the dataframe.
Is there a simple way to change the index values to 0,,1,,2,, ... n-1, where a comma is appended to each index value. So `0` becomes `0,` and `1` becomes `1,` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep it simple.

```
d.index = d.index.to_series().astype(str) + ','
```

I converted the existing index to a series so that I could conveniently add a comma to it. However I had to ensure it was of type str before I did so.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, see below:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(...)
d.index = [str(i)+',' for i in d.index]
```

But what are you trying to do with this? It seems odd to modify the index like this. If you're trying to print the the data frame in a special format or something else there is probably a better way.

For custom output, you could do something like

```
for i, row in d.iterrows():
    print i + ': ' + ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: I am trying to write the output of the data frame such that the `id` represented by the index value has a `','` followed by a list of values. So this is what it will look in the `.csv` file: 0, 100 233 etc

Comment: It works but looking for something that avoids the `for` loop as I have to reindex a very large file. Currently I have something that uses a `.map(func)` but was wondering if there was an `.index` method that does this manipulation.